# Useful additional output to NoResultException for JPA-Criteria Selections

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Whenever a `CriteriaQuery` in JPA2 does not yield a result, a `NoResultException` is thrown. This exception is not very useful in the sense that only context-information regarding line numbers where the exception is thrown might give some indication what went wrong.

I would like to have some speaking output "Looking for a class of type  and the restrictions applied where  and ". It seems, the `CriteriaQuery` is rather shy on such information, however it seems, with a combination of reflection and getter methods I will eventually get all information I want but it will be quite messy and cumbersome.

Is there a better way to retrieve the data, which went into the `CriteriaQuery`-Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are sticking to the JPA API, public interface of [CriteriaQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html) is all you have.

If you are ready to go implementation specific and use Hibernate implementation, there is more available via casting it to [org.hibernate.ejb.CriteriaQueryImpl](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/criteria/CriteriaQueryImpl.html). For example render method seems to provide access to nested class that have [getQueryString](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/criteria/CriteriaQueryCompiler.RenderedCriteriaQuery.html#getQueryString%28%29) method.

Most likely some similar ways can be found from other JPA implementations.